# struts.action.excludePattern not working

Tags: java, regex, struts2

I wanted to exclude a specific string in my URL. I have tested the regular expression using online reg tester and it works.

However, when I access the URL, it seems that struts2 is still handling the request.

Did I configure my exclusion incorrectly?

```
<constant name="struts.action.excludePattern" value="\/mystring$"/>
```

[image]

I extracted the following codes from struts2 framework and created my own test class to test the regular expression.

```
public static List<Pattern> buildExcludedPatternsList(String patterns) {
    if ((null != patterns) && (patterns.trim().length() != 0)) {
        List<Pattern> list = new ArrayList();
        String[] tokens = patterns.split(",");
        for (String token : tokens) {
            System.out.println("Token=" + token);
            list.add(Pattern.compile(token.trim()));
        }
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(list);
    }
    return null;
}


public static boolean isUrlExcluded(String uri, List<Pattern> excludedPatterns) {
    if (excludedPatterns != null) {
        for (Pattern pattern : excludedPatterns) {
            if (pattern.matcher(uri).matches()) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: please try it once with just /mystring , i know here  value should be regex but sometimes it will treate / as simple string also

Comment: like this? <constant name="struts.action.excludePattern" value="/mystring$"/>

Comment: i think it should work without $ at end also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Incorrectly. The pattern should be

```xml
<constant name="struts.action.excludePattern" value=".*/mystring$"/>
```

this pattern is compiled and matched against the URI. The code

> ```
> String uri = RequestUtils.getUri(request);
> for ( Pattern pattern : excludedPatterns ) {
>     if (pattern.matcher(uri).matches()) {
>         return true;
>     }
> }
> return false;
> ```

because it matches against whole URI string you should make your pattern greedy at the beginning.

Comment: I tested it against the method and it works. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a need for me to exclude static content resources such as /css, /javascript/ and /images as well?

Comment: No, you don't need it, they are served behind Struts, however you can configure Struts to serve static content.